# PHP MODx mysql Parse error? Where do I change the settings?

Tags: mysql, database, dns, modx

Hi I'm using MODx on a site, but something has gone wrong with the database. Any idea how I can change the PHP to point to my database?

```
« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« PHP Parse Error »

PHP error debug
  Error:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'sale'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  
  Error type/ Nr.:  Warning - 2  
  File:  /var/www/vhosts/sale.co.uk/httpdocs/manager/includes/extenders/dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php  
  Line:  89  
  Line 89 source:  if (!$this->conn = ($persist ? mysql_pconnect($host, $uid, $pwd) : mysql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd, true))) {   

Parser timing
  MySQL:  0.0000 s (0 Requests)
  PHP:  0.0144 s  
  Total:  0.0144 s  
« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« Failed to create the database connection! »

Parser timing
  MySQL:  0.0000 s (0 Requests)
  PHP:  0.0148 s  
  Total:  0.0148 s  
« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« Failed to create the database connection! »

Parser timing
  MySQL:  0.0000 s (0 Requests)
  PHP:  0.0151 s  
  Total:  0.0151 s  
« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« Failed to create the database connection! »

« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« Failed to create the database connection! »

Parser timing
  MySQL:  0.0000 s (0 Requests)
  PHP:  9.8827 s  
  Total:  9.8827 s
```

---

Do I need to edit something in here?

```
<?php

/* Database API object of MySQL
 * Written by Raymond Irving June, 2005
 *
 */

class DBAPI {

   var $conn;
   var $config;
   var $isConnected;

   /**
    * @name:  DBAPI
    *
    */
   function DBAPI($host='',$dbase='', $uid='',$pwd='',$pre=NULL,$charset='',$connection_method='SET CHARACTER SET') {
      $this->config['host'] = $host ? $host : $GLOBALS['database_server'];
      $this->config['dbase'] = $dbase ? $dbase : $GLOBALS['dbase'];
      $this->config['user'] = $uid ? $uid : $GLOBALS['database_user'];
      $this->config['pass'] = $pwd ? $pwd : $GLOBALS['database_password'];
      $this->config['charset'] = $charset ? $charset : $GLOBALS['database_connection_charset'];
      $this->config['connection_method'] =  $this->_dbconnectionmethod = (isset($GLOBALS['database_connection_method']) ? $GLOBALS['database_connection_method'] : $connection_method);
      $this->config['table_prefix'] = ($pre !== NULL) ? $pre : $GLOBALS['table_prefix'];
      $this->initDataTypes();
   }

   /**
    * @name:  initDataTypes
    * @desc:  called in the constructor to set up arrays containing the types
    *         of database fields that can be used with specific PHP types
    */
   function initDataTypes() {
      $this->dataTypes['numeric'] = array (
         'INT',
         'INTEGER',
         'TINYINT',
         'BOOLEAN',
         'DECIMAL',
         'DEC',
         'NUMERIC',
         'FLOAT',
         'DOUBLE PRECISION',
         'REAL',
         'SMALLINT',
         'MEDIUMINT',
         'BIGINT',
         'BIT'
      );
      $this->dataTypes['string'] = array (
         'CHAR',
         'VARCHAR',
         'BINARY',
         'VARBINARY',
         'TINYBLOB',
         'BLOB',
         'MEDIUMBLOB',
         'LONGBLOB',
         'TINYTEXT',
         'TEXT',
         'MEDIUMTEXT',
         'LONGTEXT',
         'ENUM',
         'SET'
      );
      $this->dataTypes['date'] = array (
         'DATE',
         'DATETIME',
         'TIMESTAMP',
         'TIME',
         'YEAR'
      );
   }

   /**
    * @name:  connect
    *
    */
   function connect($host = '', $dbase = '', $uid = '', $pwd = '', $persist = 0) {
      global $modx;
      $uid = $uid ? $uid : $this->config['user'];
      $pwd = $pwd ? $pwd : $this->config['pass'];
      $host = $host ? $host : $this->config['host'];
      $dbase = $dbase ? $dbase : $this->config['dbase'];
      $charset = $charset ? $charset : $this->config['charset'];
      $connection_method = $this->config['connection_method'];
      $tstart = $modx->getMicroTime();
      if (!$this->conn = ($persist ? mysql_pconnect($host, $uid, $pwd) : mysql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd, true))) {
         $modx->messageQuit("Failed to create the database connection!");
         exit;
      } else {
         $dbase = str_replace('`', '', $dbase); // remove the `` chars
         if (!@ mysql_select_db($dbase, $this->conn)) {
            $modx->messageQuit("Failed to select the database '" . $dbase . "'!");
            exit;
         }
         @mysql_query("{$connection_method} {$charset}", $this->conn);
         $tend = $modx->getMicroTime();
         $totaltime = $tend - $tstart;
         if ($modx->dumpSQL) {
            $modx->queryCode .= "<fieldset style='text-align:left'><legend>Database connection</legend>" . sprintf("Database connection was created in %2.4f s", $totaltime) . "</fieldset><br />";
         }
         $this->isConnected = true;
         // FIXME (Fixed by line below):
         // this->queryTime = this->queryTime + $totaltime;
         $modx->queryTime += $totaltime;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  disconnect
    *
    */
   function disconnect() {
      @ mysql_close($this->conn);
   }

   function escape($s) {
      if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string') && $this->conn) {
         $s = mysql_real_escape_string($s, $this->conn);
      } else {
         $s = mysql_escape_string($s);
      }
      return $s;
   }

   /**
    * @name:  query
    * @desc:  Mainly for internal use.
    * Developers should use select, update, insert, delete where possible
    */
   function query($sql) {
      global $modx;
      if (empty ($this->conn) || !is_resource($this->conn)) {
         $this->connect();
      }
      $tstart = $modx->getMicroTime();
      if (!$result = @ mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)) {
         $modx->messageQuit("Execution of a query to the database failed - " . $this->getLastError(), $sql);
      } else {
         $tend = $modx->getMicroTime();
         $totaltime = $tend - $tstart;
         $modx->queryTime = $modx->queryTime + $totaltime;
         if ($modx->dumpSQL) {
            $modx->queryCode .= "<fieldset style='text-align:left'><legend>Query " . ($this->executedQueries + 1) . " - " . sprintf("%2.4f s", $totaltime) . "</legend>" . $sql . "</fieldset><br />";
         }
         $modx->executedQueries = $modx->executedQueries + 1;
         return $result;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  delete
    *
    */
   function delete($from,$where='',$fields='') {
      if (!$from)
         return false;
      else {
         $table = $from;
         $where = ($where != "") ? "WHERE $where" : "";
         return $this->query("DELETE $fields FROM $table $where");
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  select
    *
    */
   function select($fields = "*", $from = "", $where = "", $orderby = "", $limit = "") {
      if (!$from)
         return false;
      else {
         $table = $from;
         $where = ($where != "") ? "WHERE $where" : "";
         $orderby = ($orderby != "") ? "ORDER BY $orderby " : "";
         $limit = ($limit != "") ? "LIMIT $limit" : "";
         return $this->query("SELECT $fields FROM $table $where $orderby $limit");
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  update
    *
    */
   function update($fields, $table, $where = "") {
      if (!$table)
         return false;
      else {
         if (!is_array($fields))
            $flds = $fields;
         else {
            $flds = '';
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
               if (!empty ($flds))
                  $flds .= ",";
               $flds .= $key . "=";
               $flds .= "'" . $value . "'";
            }
         }
         $where = ($where != "") ? "WHERE $where" : "";
         return $this->query("UPDATE $table SET $flds $where");
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  insert
    * @desc:  returns either last id inserted or the result from the query
    */
   function insert($fields, $intotable, $fromfields = "*", $fromtable = "", $where = "", $limit = "") {
      if (!$intotable)
         return false;
      else {
         if (!is_array($fields))
            $flds = $fields;
         else {
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = array_values($fields);
            $flds = "(" . implode(",", $keys) . ") " .
             (!$fromtable && $values ? "VALUES('" . implode("','", $values) . "')" : "");
            if ($fromtable) {
               $where = ($where != "") ? "WHERE $where" : "";
               $limit = ($limit != "") ? "LIMIT $limit" : "";
               $sql = "SELECT $fromfields FROM $fromtable $where $limit";
            }
         }
         $rt = $this->query("INSERT INTO $intotable $flds $sql");
         $lid = $this->getInsertId();
         return $lid ? $lid : $rt;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getInsertId
    *
    */
   function getInsertId($conn=NULL) {
      if( !is_resource($conn)) $conn =& $this->conn;
      return mysql_insert_id($conn);
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getAffectedRows
    *
    */
   function getAffectedRows($conn=NULL) {
      if (!is_resource($conn)) $conn =& $this->conn;
      return mysql_affected_rows($conn);
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getLastError
    *
    */
   function getLastError($conn=NULL) {
      if (!is_resource($conn)) $conn =& $this->conn;
      return mysql_error($conn);
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getRecordCount
    *
    */
   function getRecordCount($ds) {
      return (is_resource($ds)) ? mysql_num_rows($ds) : 0;
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getRow
    * @desc:  returns an array of column values
    * @param: $dsq - dataset
    *
    */
   function getRow($ds, $mode = 'assoc') {
      if ($ds) {
         if ($mode == 'assoc') {
            return mysql_fetch_assoc($ds);
         }
         elseif ($mode == 'num') {
            return mysql_fetch_row($ds);
         }
         elseif ($mode == 'both') {
            return mysql_fetch_array($ds, MYSQL_BOTH);
         } else {
            global $modx;
            $modx->messageQuit("Unknown get type ($mode) specified for fetchRow - must be empty, 'assoc', 'num' or 'both'.");
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getColumn
    * @desc:  returns an array of the values found on colun $name
    * @param: $dsq - dataset or query string
    */
   function getColumn($name, $dsq) {
      if (!is_resource($dsq))
         $dsq = $this->query($dsq);
      if ($dsq) {
         $col = array ();
         while ($row = $this->getRow($dsq)) {
            $col[] = $row[$name];
         }
         return $col;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getColumnNames
    * @desc:  returns an array containing the column $name
    * @param: $dsq - dataset or query string
    */
   function getColumnNames($dsq) {
      if (!is_resource($dsq))
         $dsq = $this->query($dsq);
      if ($dsq) {
         $names = array ();
         $limit = mysql_num_fields($dsq);
         for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            $names[] = mysql_field_name($dsq, $i);
         }
         return $names;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getValue
    * @desc:  returns the value from the first column in the set
    * @param: $dsq - dataset or query string
    */
   function getValue($dsq) {
      if (!is_resource($dsq))
         $dsq = $this->query($dsq);
      if ($dsq) {
         $r = $this->getRow($dsq, "num");
         return $r[0];
      }
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getXML
    * @desc:  returns an XML formay of the dataset $ds
    */
   function getXML($dsq) {
      if (!is_resource($dsq))
         $dsq = $this->query($dsq);
      $xmldata = "<xml>\r\n<recordset>\r\n";
      while ($row = $this->getRow($dsq, "both")) {
         $xmldata .= "<item>\r\n";
         for ($j = 0; $line = each($row); $j++) {
            if ($j % 2) {
               $xmldata .= "<$line[0]>$line[1]</$line[0]>\r\n";
            }
         }
         $xmldata .= "</item>\r\n";
      }
      $xmldata .= "</recordset>\r\n</xml>";
      return $xmldata;
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getTableMetaData
    * @desc:  returns an array of MySQL structure detail for each column of a
    *         table
    * @param: $table: the full name of the database table
    */
   function getTableMetaData($table) {
      $metadata = false;
      if (!empty ($table)) {
         $sql = "SHOW FIELDS FROM $table";
         if ($ds = $this->query($sql)) {
            while ($row = $this->getRow($ds)) {
               $fieldName = $row['Field'];
               $metadata[$fieldName] = $row;
            }
         }
      }
      return $metadata;
   }

   /**
    * @name:  prepareDate
    * @desc:  prepares a date in the proper format for specific database types
    *         given a UNIX timestamp
    * @param: $timestamp: a UNIX timestamp
    * @param: $fieldType: the type of field to format the date for
    *         (in MySQL, you have DATE, TIME, YEAR, and DATETIME)
    */
   function prepareDate($timestamp, $fieldType = 'DATETIME') {
      $date = '';
      if (!$timestamp === false && $timestamp > 0) {
         switch ($fieldType) {
            case 'DATE' :
               $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
               break;
            case 'TIME' :
               $date = date('H:i:s', $timestamp);
               break;
            case 'YEAR' :
               $date = date('Y', $timestamp);
               break;
            default :
               $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
               break;
         }
      }
      return $date;
   }

   /**
    * @name:  getHTMLGrid
    * @param: $params: Data grid parameters
    *         columnHeaderClass
    *         tableClass
    *         itemClass
    *         altItemClass
    *         columnHeaderStyle
    *         tableStyle
    *         itemStyle
    *         altItemStyle
    *         columns
    *         fields
    *         colWidths
    *         colAligns
    *         colColors
    *         colTypes
    *         cellPadding
    *         cellSpacing
    *         header
    *         footer
    *         pageSize
    *         pagerLocation
    *         pagerClass
    *         pagerStyle
    *
    */
   function getHTMLGrid($dsq, $params) {
      global $base_path;
      if (!is_resource($dsq))
         $dsq = $this->query($dsq);
      if ($dsq) {
         include_once MODX_BASE_PATH . '/manager/includes/controls/datagrid.class.php';
         $grd = new DataGrid('', $dsq);

         $grd->noRecordMsg = $params['noRecordMsg'];

         $grd->columnHeaderClass = $params['columnHeaderClass'];
         $grd->cssClass = $params['cssClass'];
         $grd->itemClass = $params['itemClass'];
         $grd->altItemClass = $params['altItemClass'];

         $grd->columnHeaderStyle = $params['columnHeaderStyle'];
         $grd->tableStyle = $params['tableStyle'];
         $grd->itemStyle = $params['itemStyle'];
         $grd->altItemStyle = $params['altItemStyle'];

         $grd->columns = $params['columns'];
         $grd->fields = $params['fields'];
         $grd->colWidths = $params['colWidths'];
         $grd->colAligns = $params['colAligns'];
         $grd->colColors = $params['colColors'];
         $grd->colTypes = $params['colTypes'];
         $grd->colWraps = $params['colWraps'];

         $grd->cellPadding = $params['cellPadding'];
         $grd->cellSpacing = $params['cellSpacing'];
         $grd->header = $params['header'];
         $grd->footer = $params['footer'];
         $grd->pageSize = $params['pageSize'];
         $grd->pagerLocation = $params['pagerLocation'];
         $grd->pagerClass = $params['pagerClass'];
         $grd->pagerStyle = $params['pagerStyle'];
         return $grd->render();
      }
   }

   /**
   * @name:  makeArray
   * @desc:  turns a recordset into a multidimensional array
   * @return: an array of row arrays from recordset, or empty array
   *          if the recordset was empty, returns false if no recordset
   *          was passed
   * @param: $rs Recordset to be packaged into an array
   */
   function makeArray($rs=''){
      if(!$rs) return false;
      $rsArray = array();
      $qty = $this->getRecordCount($rs);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++) $rsArray[] = $this->getRow($rs);
      return $rsArray;
   }

   /**
    * @name getVersion
    * @desc returns a string containing the database server version
    *
    * @return string
    */
   function getVersion() {
       return mysql_get_server_info();
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned I'd check using phpAdmin that your logon credentials to your modX database is correct first. Once you are sure this is working ok then in modX the database configuration I believe is defined in the file

`<site_home_directory>/manager/includes/config.inc.php`

Right at the top it has this block which you should be able to edit accordingly.

```
<?php
/**
 *  MODx Configuration file
 */
$database_type = 'mysql';
$database_server = 'localhost';
$database_user = 'db_username';
$database_password = 'mypassword';
$database_connection_charset = 'utf8';
$database_connection_method = 'SET NAMES';
$dbase = '`db_name`';
$table_prefix = 'modx_';
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the file, it says that it was unable to connect to database, try to connect to database and then execute your queries.

Use **[mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)** function to connect to the database.

Also check to make sure that you are specifying correct credentials for the database connection.

Comment: Thanks very much, would I need to edit the php or use php admin panel database?

Comment: just check which php file is used to connect to database, try searching in your php files for the keywork either mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect and then edit that file with appropriate db credentials. Thanks

Comment: mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect? There isn't any file with that name?

Comment: i said search those terms in all your php files.